# Excel VBA - How to trigger Listbox Click from another control

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on a small project using Excel VBA.  I have a listbox (listbox1) on the sheet that is populated with client names from a SQLServer database when the worksheet is open.  Clicking an item in the listbox selects and displays services provided. This is all working correctly.

I have added two data picker controls that are to be used to reduce the rows selected, depending on the dates entered.  I would like to trigger the click event on the listbox with the selected entry when the dates change in the date picker controls.

My VBA is a bit rusty and I have not, for the life of me, been able to determine how to write the code in the data picker control change event to trigger the click on the list box.  I've tried several ways, always getting an error indicating that the "object doesn't support the property or method".  Here is the simple code from the latest attempt:

```
Private Sub StartDatePicker_Change()

    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListBox1_Click

End Sub
```

I'm sure that there is something simple that I'm missing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This will be because 'ListBox1_Click' is not a native property of an Excel worksheet. You may have a procedure called that but it belongs to a specific instance of a worksheet My VBA is also a bit rusty so I can't given you a full solution but hopefully that will help you on your way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** after OP's further specifications (see last part)

I'm not sure of you goal but with an ActveX Listbox control on the sheet, this will trigger its click event handler:

```
Private Sub StartDatePicker_Change()
    Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

of course, being an ActiveX control, this code is to be placed in the sheet code pane

---

or you could

- move all your current `ListBox1_Click` code doing the populating work to a specific sub :

  ```
  Sub Populate()
      ... move here all code from ListBox1_Click doing the populating work
  End Sub
  ```
- change your `Listbox1_Click()` event handler as follows:

  ```
  Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
      Populate ' this will call the sub that does the populating work

      ... here goes other code (if any) directly connected with ListBox1 click event but not relevant for populating
  End Sub
  ```
- change your `StartDatePicker_Change()` event as follows:

  ```
  Private Sub StartDatePicker_Change()
      Populate 'this will do the populating work
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  This does trigger the click event, but it also deselects the item in the listbox previously selected.  Clicking on an item in the listbox populates a number of rows with data related to that client based on the client name and the dates in the two data picker controls.  (Think services provided between those dates).  The goal is to trigger the click event each time that that date information in either of the pickers changes so that the services provided change with them.  Hopefully that makes sense....

Comment: see edited answer. If it solves your question then you may consider marking answer as accepted. thank you

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply.  The 2nd option worked very well.  I moved the code that populates the list of services to a separate sub and call it from both of the date picker controls and from the listbox click event.  Works well now.  Thanks for the tips...  I should have sorted this out on my own, but I was fixated on triggering the click event on the list box.  Great feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If I create a ListBox and add assign a macro to right click context menu the macro ends up in its own module.

I am then able to simply call it by the name of the macro like `ListBox1_Click`. Did you try that already?